# MacBook Pro 16” and HDMI splitter not working

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, hdmi

I recently purchased several HDMI splitters to use with my MacBook Pro (16"). I was hoping to connect one of them like this:

```
                   ------ Monitor
                  /
MacBook Pro 16"  |
                  \
                   ----- ATEM Mini Pro
```

But, the display won't display anything. I've read this is because the laptop tries querying the monitor about what resolution it supports and can't but I've seen other people use this setup with success.

Can anyone tell me why the display won't turn on, or turns on with flickering?

Here is the HDMI splitter: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07DQBY5TX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1&fpw=alm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DQBY5TX)

The ATEM Mini Pro: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/atemmini/techspecs/W-APS-14

And here's a guide someone made showing the same connections working. I am going to use the other splitters in similar ways but haven't had luck with the above setup: https://dslrvideoshooter.com/ultimate-camera-rig/